# Change firefox playback bar into a onclick button for audio

Tags: javascript, html, firefox, audio

SAME ISSUE! As we all know firefox and audio is a problem because of patents and such. I found this little code on the internet to play my sounfile.

I would like to play multiple files instead of just one while having the display bar not show up in the browser

- you can change the player width to 0 but than the user can not click the play button :P
  Is there a way of possibly having the sound play on click of a link or button.

Please note. Do not give me codes that have no compatibility outside chrome and ie.

HTML

```
    <audio id="audioplayer" preload controls loop style="width:400px;">
    <source src="sounds/sound1.mp3">
    <source src="sounds/sound1.caf">
    </audio>
```

Javascript

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var audioTag = document.createElement('audio');
    if (!(!!(audioTag.canPlayType) && ("no" != audioTag.canPlayType("audio/mpeg")) &&  ("" !=     audioTag.canPlayType("audio/mpeg")))) {
    AudioPlayer.embed("audioplayer", {soundFile: "sounds/sound1.mp3"});
    }
    </script>
```

RECAP:
Have the sound play on a button or link click.
Have multiple sounds available to play (not just one)
Compatibility with firefox
non visible soundbar.

Comment: Did you try your suggestion? What happened?

Comment: it became 0 length. impossible to click

Comment: You probably want to make your own play button.

Comment: Create a button, handle its click event, use the DOM API to play the audio.  None of this is any different in Firefox, except for which formats it supports.

Comment: Can you please show me a working example because I have no idea what dom api is and such...

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLAudioElement

Answer (score 0):

Still learning myself. But this is a button, with a script to play an audio file. (part of my own solution) Plays only 1 sound at a time, but doesn't show anything about it.
You could also make a funtion like this, without setting the src, using the pause() command.
currenttime is used to change the part where the audio file was.

```
<a href="#" onclick="playSnd('sounds/close_chat.wav');">Sound play button</a><br>

<script>

sound = new Audio();

function playSnd(soundSrc) {
sound.src = soundSrc;
sound.play();
}
</script>
```